# "Right Click > Open In Terminal" Does not work if I activate tmux whenever I start a new shell session

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 20 Ulyana, Cinnamon 4.6.6

I am using the following code to activate tmux whenever I start a new shell session.

```
function tmux-as-default-terminal () {

  if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]]  && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    tmux attach -t default || tmux new -s default
  fi

}

tmux-as-default-terminal
```

However, It has a small issue. When I right click a directory and click "Open In Terminal", it does not open that path. Instead it just open the previous tmux session.

What could be done here?

**Update 1**

I figured out `tmux new-session -c $PWD` open a new tmux session in current directory.

`tmux attach -t 0 -c $PWD \; new-window \;` attach to existing session and open a new window with current directory.

This bit of information might be important to solve this puzzle.

**Update 2**

From [Is it possible to send input to a tmux session without connecting to it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409863/206574) I found out that I can use

```
$ tmux new -d -s mySession
$ tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "^U"
$ tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "cd /tmp" ENTER
$ tmux a -t mySession
```

to cd to a directory in current session.

**Update 3**

A solution with some strings attached

```
function tmux-as-default-terminal () {

  if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]]  && [ -z "$TMUX" ]
  then

    if tmux has-session -t default
    then
        tmux send-keys -t default.0 "^U"
        tmux send-keys -t default.0 "cd $PWD &> /dev/null" ENTER
        tmux send-keys -t default.0 "^L"
        tmux attach-session -t default.0
    else
        tmux new-session -s default -c $PWD
    fi
  fi

}

tmux-as-default-terminal
```

It works, as long as I **do not open multiple terminals simultaneously**.

Comment: Isn't the context menu (rt-click) part of the window-manager instead of part of the shell? I don't use Mint or Cinnamon, but it seems that the context menu would be associated with the original contents of the window and would not know about any change to that contents made by tmux.

Comment: I have opened a new issue in nemo repo https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2463

Comment: Good deal. Hopefully they can get it sorted out.

Comment: Currently I am looking at https://superuser.com/questions/492266/run-or-send-a-command-to-a-tmux-pane-in-a-running-tmux-session

Comment: One more thing that might be useful is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118381

Comment: That looks like how you may configure tmux to tell the window manager to adjust the context menu behavior based on what tmux is giving it. I'm spoiled, I just have a set of 9 tabs I use in konsole and use shift + left/right arrow keys to navigate. Let us know if that page solves your issue.